# Ionic access component from the HTML file

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Hi I have the following component that i have created in Ionic 4 using ionic g component [name of component].

I have the following page that I created in ionic.

```
 <ion-content>
  <ion-grid class="ion-no-padding">
  <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <app-displaylocation>

        </app-displaylocation>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

the app-displaylocation is the component i created. Now i want to tell the componentto run a certain method when it is loaded. I have created a method named trackuser() but I am unable to call it from the html code using

```
(onLoad) = "trackuser()"
```

sinceit simply tells me that it cannot find the method. How can i call I call a method in the component from my pages html file?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with `ViewChild` and the `AfterViewInit` hook:

- `ViewChild` let you select a child component from the parent
- `AfterViewInit` is triggered when the parent view (with all its children) is initialized. When this happens, we can get the refer the child component and invoke its public method `trackUser`

Here's the main code to do it

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HelloComponent} from './hello.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <hello></hello>
    <p>
      check the console, trackUser of helloComponent is called from the parent
    </p>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  name = 'Angular';

  @ViewChild(HelloComponent) helloComp: HelloComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.helloComp.trackUser();
  }


}
```

and also the stackblitz if case you need: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ui779c